# yii framework CActiveform dependent dropdown won't work inside pjax'ed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, yii-extensions, pjax

here's my dependent dropdown php code:

```
<?php $find= new SomeModule;
      $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
         'action'=> Yii::app()->createUrl('someurl'),
         'method'=>'post',
         'id'=>'filter-id',
         'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
      )); ?>

<?php 
echo $form->dropDownList($find,'category',
    CHtml::listData(BaseCategory::model()->findAll(array(
       'order' => 'name', 
       'condition'=>'type=:postID',
       'params'=>array(':postID'=>1),
    )), 'id', 'name'),
    array(
       'prompt'=>'Select Category', 
       'ajax'=>array(
       'type'=>'POST',
       'url'=>CController::createUrl('someurl/searchCategory'),
       'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($find,'category2')
    ),
 )
 );
?>
<?php 
 echo $form->dropDownList($find,'category2', array(), array(
    'prompt'=>'Select Sub Category',
   )
);
?>
```

I need to place this php code inside pjax content. Working fine when the page refreshed. But when it's loaded using pjax, this dependent dropdown won't work.

**question:**

How to make this dependent dropdown working when its loaded using pjax? What code should I add in:

```
 $(document)
    .on('pjax:success', function() {

    })
```

to make this dependent dropdown works? Is there any script to "reload" this php code, so the dependent dropdown works? Or is there another solution?

Comment: Did you check the javascript console for errors? Is the request being made successfully? Is there a response?

Comment: yes i did, there's no response. It's only works when the page refreshed. any idea?